# Visual Studio Code cannot build the default dotnet core class library

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, build, class-library, vscode-tasks

I cannot get VS Code to build an empty class library while dotnet core can quite happily.

In PowerShell I create a folder called `CoreTesting`, navigate into it and launch VS Code with `code`.

I hit `` CTRL + ` `` to enter the terminal and navigate into the solution's folder.

I then enter `dotnet new classlib --name Common`, see the new folder `Common` and enter `dotnet build .\Common\` to build the class library. All is well.

I add the Common folder to VS Code and hit `CTRL + SHIFT + B` and see `No build task to run found. Configure Build Task...`, so I hit `return` and see `Create tasks.json file from template`, so I hit `return` again and see:

- `MSBuild`
- `maven`
- `.NET Core`
- `Others`

So I select `.NET Core` and see that a `.vscode` folder is created containing `tasks.json`. This file contains:

```js
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet build",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

I hit `CTRL + SHIFT + B` again and see the option `build Common`, so I hit `return` and see this:

```
> Executing task in folder Common: dotnet build <

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.225-preview+g5ebeba52a1 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

The structure I can see is this:

- `Common\`

  - `.vscode\`

    - `tasks.json`
  - `bin\`
  - `obj\`
  - `Class1.cs`
  - `Common.csproj`

What have I done wrong?

Comment: No; I've added the folder structure to the post, to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your problem on v1.41.1 for Windows.  In doing so it created this `tasks.json` which is similar to yours...

```js
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "build",
                // Ask dotnet build to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

When you invoke a task, it defaults to using the workspace folder (`CoreTesting`) path as the working directory.  However, the project file is a directory beneath in `Common`, hence the error `The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.`

A quick fix for this is to simply open the directory with the project file as the workspace folder (i.e. `File` → `Open Folder...` → Select the `Common` directory).

Alternatively, if that solution is undesirable then with `CoreTesting` opened as the workspace folder you can configure the task to execute with a different working directory.  To do this, set the task's `options.cwd` property...

```js
{
    /* snip */
    "tasks": [
        {
            /* snip */
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Common"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I found this property in the [Schema for `tasks.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix#_schema-for-tasksjson), and it's also mentioned in the [Custom tasks section of the Tasks documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks).  After making either change above the library builds successfully for me.